# Декомпиляция байткода

Tags: perl

Работал с человеком, который писал на perl. Теперь его нет, а понадобилось кое-что подправить в исходнике, как это можно сделать?

Comment: нужно просить сорцы. Обычно это решается административным способом.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=perl+decompile&oq=perl+decomp&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7375j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать в любом текстовом редакторе. Перл-скрипт это обычный текстовый файл.